# How do I use ng-app with RequireJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I'm learning RequireJs and I'm stumped on how to use Angular directives in my HTML that require angular to already be loaded.

Consider this example -

**index.html:**

```
<script src="myUrl/require.js" data-main="js/main.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  ...
</div>
```

**main.js:**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths : {
        'angular' : 'myUrl/angular.min',
        },
    shim : {
        'angular' : {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'myApp':{
            deps: ['angular']
        }
    },
    deps : ['angular', 'myApp']
});
```

**myApp.js:**

```
require(['angular'], function(angular){
    angular.module('myApp',[]);
});
```

Running this code will get me a `Module Unavailable` error, which makes me think that the `myApp` code just hasnt been run it because RequireJs is still spinning its wheels. How can I avoid this apparent race condition?

Comment: Sorry for the question but has any sense use requirejs with angular? Why not manage the dependencies with the angular's DI ?

Comment: @ianaya89 see: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-requirejs-angularjs-applications/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load Angular dynamically with RequireJS, you should drop the `ng-app` attribute and initialize your application with [`angular.bootstrap`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap).